# Framing Sentences based on keywords

Tags: nlp, nlg

Given a few specific words, which techniques of Natural Language Processing can I use to achieve creating a meaningful sentence from those words?

eg.

**Words:**
jackets, highest sale, sweaters, lowest sale

**Sentence:**
Jackets exhibited the highest sales while sweaters sold the least.

If my question is too broad, let me know so I can ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by making use of the **Natural Language Generation**, Python Library , `nlglib`

The solution I came up with is depicted through the Python Code below.

```
import nlglib
realise_en = Realiser(host='nlg.kutlak.info', port=40000)

p = Clause(NP('jackets'), VP('achieve','highest sales'))
p['TENSE'] = 'PAST'
q = Clause(NP('sweaters'), VP('exhibit','lowest sales'))
q['TENSE'] = 'PAST'
print(realise_en(p))
print(realise_en(q))
r=Clause(realise_en(p)[:-1],'while',realise_en(q))
print(r)
```

This prints the statements

```
Jackets achieved highest sales.
Sweaters exhibited lowest sales.
Jackets achieved highest sales while Sweaters exhibited lowest sales.
```

This is the best solution I found so far.